# Broken MiKTeX after update in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: miktex, ubuntu

Most recent MiKTeX update requires running an additional configuration step after installing it.
Their website now says users have to run `miktexsetup finish` to actually conclude the installation. Now, when I execute that command I'm getting the following error:

```
219548 [.libmpm]: initializing MPM library version 2.9.6584
219716 [.setup]:   Report
219746 [.setup]: 
219906 [.setup]: Date: Wednesday, February 14, 2018
219931 [.setup]: Time: 01:14:06
219991 [.setup]: OS version: Linux 4.4.0-112-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018 x86_64
220012 [.setup]: SharedSetup: false
220030 [.setup]: UserRoots: <none specified>
220051 [.setup]: UserData: <none specified>
220071 [.setup]: UserConfig: <none specified>
220092 [.setup]: CommonRoots: <none specified>
220113 [.setup]: CommonData: <none specified>
220137 [.setup]: CommonConfig: <none specified>
220163 [.setup]: Installation: /home/eddy/.miktex/texmfs/install
220192 [.setup]: initexmf --create-config-file=miktex/config/miktex.ini --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=0 --disable-installer --verbose:
243632 [.core]: forking...
245195 [.core]: start reading the pipe
278935 [.core]: read 283 bytes from the pipe
279021 [.core]: waiting for process 16833
279082 [.core]: process 16833 exited with status 0
279163 [.setup]: initexmf --update-fndb --disable-installer --verbose:
279230 [.core]: forking...
280565 [.core]: start reading the pipe
281062 [.core]: read 776 bytes from the pipe
281121 [.core]: waiting for process 16837
281187 [.core]: process 16837 exited with status 0
281287 [.setup]: initexmf --force --mklinks --disable-installer --verbose:
281370 [.core]: forking...
282634 [.core]: start reading the pipe
282811 [.core]: read 210 bytes from the pipe
282890 [.core]: waiting for process 16838
282981 [.core]: process 16838 exited with status 0
283100 [.setup]: initexmf --mkmaps --mklangs --disable-installer --verbose:
283193 [.core]: forking...
284642 [.core]: start reading the pipe
285097 [.core]: read 537 bytes from the pipe
285162 [.core]: waiting for process 16839
285234 [.core]: process 16839 exited with status 1
285421 [.core]: The executed process did not succeed.
285459 [.core]: Data: exitCode="1", fileName="/usr/bin/initexmf"
285482 [.core]: Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/Core/Process/Process.cpp:166
miktexsetup: The executed process did not succeed.
miktexsetup: Data: exitCode="1", fileName="/usr/bin/initexmf"
```

It was working just fine in my computer with the previous version. How do I fix this?

link to issue in MiKTeX's issue tracker: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/67

Comment: BTW, I get exactly the same error message when I execute it in admin mode: `sudo miktexsetup --shared=yes finish`

Comment: Make a bug report in the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: I did it. I posted it in here as well just to find out if it has happened to anyone else and if they managed to fix it.

Comment: Then edit the question and add a link to the issue.

Comment: Ok, I just dit it.

Comment: MikTex is purely for Windows. Use TexLive instead.

Comment: @subhamsoni no, there is an _experimental_ Linux version. https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx, though I also recommend using TeXLive, but that is just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at least until they finally manage to fix this last release I found a partial solution:

I removed miktex, downloaded the .deb (http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb/pool/universe/m/miktex/miktex-2.9.6530-1-linux-x86_64.deb) for the previous version (2.9.6530) and `dpkg -i` it. And that one works!

I'm gonna comment the line corresponding to miktext in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list to avoid it from getting updated for a while...